# How do I add conditional shipping cost to an order?

Tags: 6, ubercart

I am building an e-commerce site. When a shippable item is added to the cart I have to add some fixed shipping cost to the order which I am able to do with [flat rate](http://api.ubercart.me/api/search/6/uc_flatrate). But I have to 
add an option "Residential Delivery Fee" while showing shipping cost on checkout page. If user select this option during checkout then I have to add another shipping cost to the order.

I am unable to figure out that how to add this conditional shipping cost.

Comment: If possible shift to Drupal Commerce and use the Rules magic sauce :P

Comment: Drupal Commerce for Drupal 6? That's some magic ...

Answer (score 1):

Here the idea,

1. Using `hook_checkout_pane()` include your option *Residential Delivery Fee* as checkbox
2. Then while saving order check if user selected this option. Use `hook_order`
3. If user chose this option, you can add your shipping charge as line item with the function `uc_order_line_item_add()`.

foreg:

```
function hook_order(){
switch ($op) {
.....................
case 'save':
if($arg1->residential){
//if the checkbox was selected, we add the line item to the order. the following function  will add 100 to order total as shipping charge
uc_order_line_item_add
    (
      $arg1->order_id, 
      'shipping',
      t('Residential Delivery Fee'), 
      100, 
      NULL,
      array () 
    );

 }
}
```